# Performance cost of increasing the number of components in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, components

I'm currently building an app and I have a pretty complex component to rework. I was considering splitting sub functionalities of this component into various other components for ease of maintaining. And then I asked myself if increasing the number of component types had a cost on the overall performance of my app.

To add a bit of context I'm working on a search page that references songs playable on a twitch stream. Each song is an item of a big list (the list is lazy loaded as the user scroll and I use a virtual scroller to minimize performance issues), for each item I have various pieces of information to display (some tags, some meta data, etc) and I wanted to split my component in sub-component to reduce the size of the song component (currently rocking 1200 lines of code).

So, would splitting this big component into sub-component have an impact on performance and if so is it mitigable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to having more maintainable code, you may actually see a performance improvement by breaking the large component into sub-components based on how Vue handles re-rendering when it detects changes in a component.

In my experience, Vue handles `v-for` loops over sub-components efficiently - even very complex sub-components.

As you add more components, you might want to consider implementing [Vuex store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) and (maybe) an [event bus](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus).